# What is different between maximal cyclic subgroup with cyclic maximal subgroup?

Tags: group-theory

What is different between  "maximal cyclic subgroup" with "cyclic maximal subgroup"?

Are these are equal or different?(example?)

Comment: Can you give an example of where you've seen the phrase "cyclic maximal subgroup"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maximal cyclic subgroup is a cyclic subgroup that is maximal among all cyclic subgroups. That is there is no other cyclic subgroup that would contain it while there might be other non-cyclic subgroups that are larger.

A cyclic maximal subgroup is a maximal subgroup (among all subgroups) that is cyclic. That is it is a maximal subgroup that happens to be cyclic.

I think this is the default reading, but I would not rely on everybody using or understanding it in this way.

Note that a cyclic maximal subgroup is always a maximal cyclic subgroup but the converse might not be true.

- In the additive group  $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/p^3\mathbb{Z} $. 
  The subgroup $ \{0 \} \times \mathbb{Z}/p^3\mathbb{Z}$ is a maximal cyclic subgroup, yet not a maximal subgroup and thus not a cyclic maximal subgroup either.
- In the additive group  $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/p^3\mathbb{Z} $. 
  The subgroup $ \{0 \} \times \mathbb{Z}/p^3\mathbb{Z}$ is a maximal cyclic subgroup, and also a maximal subgroup and thus a cyclic maximal subgroup.

Comment: I agree with your reading. In a similar vein you have "free abelian group" vs  "abelian free group".